# Menus - child of text separator item type to NOT be a 'child' in the URL

Tags: menu, menu-item

I want to create a sub menu, where the parent item is text only (not a link).

I've done so by making the parent item a `text separator` type menu item and making sub-menu items by selecting it as the parent for other menu items.

Now the URLs of the pages who are sub-menu items of that text separator are `/parent-page/page`.

How can I achieve my inital task but with the URLs of the sub-menu items just be `root.com/page`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways. If your needs are only as you say then then first of these is best.

1. Use the direct alias plugin https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/direct-alias/
2. Make the real menu items in a hidden menu and then add menu aliases to the visible menu
3. install an sef component like artio JoomSEF which lets you override every url